# How do I Get SQL Text From ColdFusion Service

Tags: coldfusion

I've been given a project that uses AngularJS and ColdFusion as a Service.  I understand Angular but I've never worked with ColdFusion before.  Within the CFFunction Tag in a ColdFusionComponent I have some complex SQL that is being generated.  In addition to the actual data being returned from the Service I would like to have the service return the actual text of the SQL executed.  Can someone tell me how this can be done?

Comment: That depends on the format of the data. If you're returning a struct that contains the data, it woudln't be very difficult to add one more key to said struct. But, if you're returning an array of results, it of course wouldn't make sense to return an additional string along with that array result, just like php or whatever other language you're familiar with. At the end of the day, all webservers output the same content; text. Decide what you want your output to look like then alter the service such that it returns that output.

Comment: _the actual text of the SQL executed_ - in order to get the SQL statement that was executed you can use the `result` attribute of the `<cfquery>` tag. When you include that attribute then ColdFusion will return more information about the query including the SQL statement that was executed. [See the docs here](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfquery.html) under the "usage" section (about midway down the page) for more information.

Comment: I nominate @Miguel-F to answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*From the comments*

In order to get the SQL statement that was executed you can use the result attribute of the `<cfquery>` tag. When you include that attribute then ColdFusion will return more information about the query including the SQL statement that was executed. [See the docs here](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfquery.html) under the "usage" section (about midway down the page) for more information.

From the referenced documentation:

> The cfquery tag also returns the following result variables in a structure. You can access these variables with a prefix of the name you specified in the result attribute. For example, if you assign the name myResult to the result attribute, you would retrieve the name of the SQL statement that was executed by accessing #myResult.sql#. The result attribute provides a way for functions or CFCs that are called from multiple pages, possibly at the same time, to avoid overwriting results of one call with another. The result variable of INSERT queries contains a key-value pair that is the automatically generated ID of the inserted row; this is available only for databases that support this feature. If more than one record was inserted, the value can be a list of IDs. The key name is database-specific.
>
> ```
> Variable name              Description
> result_name.sql            The SQL statement that was executed.
> result_name.recordcount    Number of records (rows) returned from the query.
> result_name.cached         True if the query was cached; False otherwise.
> result_name.sqlparameters  An ordered Array of cfqueryparam values.
> result_name.columnList     Comma-separated list of the query columns.
> result_name.ExecutionTime  Cumulative time required to process the query.
> result_name.IDENTITYCOL    SQL Server only. The ID of an inserted row.
> result_name.ROWID          Oracle only. The ID of an inserted row. This is not the
>                            primary key of the row, although you can retrieve rows 
>                            based on this ID.
> result_name.SYB_IDENTITY   Sybase only. The ID of an inserted row.
> result_name.SERIAL_COL     Informix only. The ID of an inserted row.
> result_name.GENERATED_KEY  MySQL only. The ID of an inserted row. MySQL 3 does not 
>                            support this feature.
> result_name.GENERATEDKEY   Supports all databases. The ID of an inserted row.
> ```

Comment: Thanks Kevin/Miguel-F/Dan.

Comment: Thanks Kevin/Miguel-F/Dan.  I'm making changes to cfc file but not seeing changes in IE Developer Tools for some reason.

Comment: In order to see things in the IE dev tools (client side) the data will need to be passed back from your cfc (server side). So you will need to pass the `result_name.sql` value back from your cfc. _Assuming that is what you are after_. It might be worth adding a new question regarding your cfc specifically as this original question has been answered.